# NHibernate create object from only collection of children

Tags: nhibernate

I have a table logging web page hits. Something like: {VisitId, VisitorId, Url, Date}
(The visitor ID is a GUID stored in a cookie)

I would like to create a Visitor object that has a collection of Visit objects.

```
class Visitor {
  public virtual Guid VisitorId { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

Rather than add another table for Visitor, can NHibernate create this object just from the collection of Visits?
Ideally, I would like to write:

```
var visitor = session.Get<Visitor>(guidFromCookie)
```

And then be able to work with the Visits list and persist changes back to the DB.

(I'm using FluentNHibernate and NHibernate 3.0)

I'm new to NHibernate, but it seems the something should be possible using a custom IEntityPersister, or is this too low level and loads of work? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "create this object", do you mean retrieve?  What is your reason for not having a visitor table?  You could use the [criteria API](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria) or hbm to load a list of visits by the guid if you don't want a visitor entity/table.

Comment: Yes, I want to the retrieve the object from ISession.

Comment: I don't have a Visitor table because I don't need it really. It would just have a single Id column.

Comment: I think you will need a table if you're wanting to use "Get".  Otherwise, you'll have to use some way of querying the Visit table that doesn't use a primary key (i.e. CreateCriteria, hql, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you mapped `Visitor` and made it Lazy Loaded, you might be able to do this.  You'd have to tell NHibernate that the table existed, even though it didn't.  However, when you want to get the Visitor object (note that the only property mapped is the Id), then instead of using `.Get()`, use `.Load()` which will return an uninitialized proxy.  So you'll have an entity, but it won't actually hit the database, so it will never know that the table doesn't exist.

```
public class VisitorMap : ClassMap<Visitor>
{
    public VisitorMap()
    {
        Table("SomeNonExistentTable");
        LazyLoad(); // should be the default anyway
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();
        HasMany(x => x.Visits)
            .AsList()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

...and then...

```
var visitor = session.Load<Visitor>(guidFromCookie);
foreach(var visit in visitor.Visits)
{
    // do wonderful things
}
```